# como corrigir este erro ? exp: 125 < 55

Tags: javascript, comparação

como corrigir este erro ?

se  inserir firstNumber = 125 , e secondNumber = 055
o resultado : 125 > 055
se firstNumber = 125 e secondNumber = 55
resultado :   125 < 55

codigo do livro: Javascriptme pag 23 e 24.

```
<body>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        var firstNumber, //declare first variable
            secondNumber; //declare second variable
        firstNumber = window.prompt("Enter first Number:", 0);
        secondNumber = window.prompt("Enter second integer:", "0");

        document.writeln("<H1>Comparison Output</H1>");
        document.writeln("<TABLE BORDER = '2' WIDTH = '100%'>"); // Creates table   

        if (firstNumber == secondNumber)
            document.writeln("<TR><TD>" + firstNumber + " = " + secondNumber +
                "</TD></TR>"); // Creates rows and columns
        if (firstNumber != secondNumber)
            document.writeln("<TR><TD>" + firstNumber + " Not equal to " + secondNumber +
                "</TD></TR>");

        if (firstNumber > secondNumber)
            document.writeln("<TR><TD>" + firstNumber + " > " + secondNumber +
                "</TD></TR>")
        else
            document.writeln("<TR><TD>" + firstNumber + " < " + secondNumber +
                "</TD></TR>");
        // Display results
        document.writeln("</TABLE>");

    </SCRIPT>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o resultado de `window.prompt("Enter first Number:", 0);` [é uma string e não um número](https://jsfiddle.net/ra71xLkv/). Assim o que está a acontecer é que estás a comparar texto, e aí conta o comprimento primeiro.

Tens de converter essa String num numero com `parseFloat`, `parseInt` (só para inteiros) ou `Number`.

Por exemplo assim:

```
firstNumber = Number(window.prompt("Enter first Number:", 0));
secondNumber = Number(window.prompt("Enter second integer:", "0"));
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/8a9rd1rt/

Comment: Para adicionar fonte à resposta: [Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: As variáveis `firstNumber` e `secondNumber` podem ter o valor `NaN` caso o usuário preencha um texto ao invés de número.

Comment: @Nevershowmyface pois, mas o intuito da app não é essa, o prompt pede _"insert number"_. Mas caso queiras essa segurança Filipe, podes fazer `...first Number:", 0)) || 0;` no final de casa uma dessas linhas. Assim ele assume zero se a conversão falhar.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Sergio, e  e pela rapidez de resposta. assim ja funciona direito com valores numericos , e inteiros .  ||0 (or 0 ) isso impressionou-me hehe , esta linguagem é marada.

Comment: Ótimo. Pois como `Number('foo')` dá `NaN` que tem valor `false` dá para fazer assim :)